# linux - how to run a selenium-server-standalone?

Tags: java, linux, selenium

I created a `.sh` file with the following content:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./opt/webdrivers/geckodriver
```

I already made sure that the file `/opt/webdrivers/geckodriver` has permission to get executed by using `chmod 770` and I even changed the user to root.

But this is the result if I execute my `.sh` file:

```
root@mycomputer:/opt/Selenium# ./selenium.sh
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./opt/webdrivers/geckodriver
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:742)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:282)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:265)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.<init>(JCommander.java:210)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$1.setConfiguration(GridLauncherV3.java:227)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.buildLauncher(GridLauncherV3.java:155)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:75)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the parameters right after `-jar`:

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./opt/webdrivers/geckodriver selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar
```

**Note**: This is a knowledge sharing answer ([share your knowledge, Q&A-style](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))